# Creating a circle in a container, according to height. CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css, geometry, height

I want to create a circle in a container, but the container height can change, but I still want the circle to have the same height as the container.

Is that possible? I only know of solutions when I know the height, width in pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-bartik-4od1mk?file=/src/styles.css)

The element with class `circle` will get the height of the  `container` element always.

**CSS**

```
container {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 100%;  You no longer need it when using aspect-ratio*/ 
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I might have been sloppy in my question. The problem is that I don't know the height of the container, since its an image who can have different heights depending on the image. And the container is much much wider than the circle, so I dont want to use width in the circle, it should depend on the height of the container.

Comment: Then in that case using the `aspect-ratio` property is your best option here if you don't mind supporting older browsers. I have updated my answer but @A Haworth saw your comment first and has already added it.

Answer (score 2):

Set the height of the circle element to 100% (ie the height of its container) and set the width by setting aspect-ratio to 1 / 1.

```css
.container {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 40vw;
  background-color: pink;
}
.circle {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="circle"></div><div>
```